# Django radio button values in views

Tags: python, django, forms, radio-button

I'm using Radio buttons in django forms to record gender fields of object Person, as below.

Person Model

```
class Person(models.Model):
   GENDER = [
    ('MALE','Male'),
    ('FEMALE','Female')  
     ]

  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
  email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
  gender = models.CharField(choices=GENDER, null=True, blank=True, max_length=30)
```

My PersonForm

```
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):

   GENDER = [
      ('MALE','Male'),
      ('FEMALE','Female')  
       ]

   first_name = forms.CharField(label="First Name")
   last_name = forms.CharField(label="Last Name")
   email= forms.CharField(label="Email")

   gender = forms.ChoiceField(
     label='Gender',
     choices=GENDER,
     widget=forms.RadioSelect(),)
    
    
   class Meta:
     model = Client
     fields = ['first_name', 'last_name','email','gender']

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
    


   def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
      cleaned_data = super(PersonForm, self).clean()
    
            
      return cleaned_data
```

Then my create_person_view(()

```
def create_person_view(request):



   if request.method == 'POST':
 
      form = PersonForm(request.POST)
    

    
   
      if form.is_valid():
       
          form.save():
        
          return render(request, 'person/view_persons.html')

     else:
          form = PersonForm()
    
   


    return render(request, "person/create_person.html", {"person_form": form})
```

Now, I save the form and saves fine. The problem comes in when getting the saved data from database and passing to templates.

Specifically when I do

```
Gender: {{person.gender}}
```

It gives:

```
Gender: <django.forms.fields.ChoiceField object at 0x7fd82ae866a0>
```

I wanna display the real value of gender. Any help? Will be really appreciated.